# jQuery UI slider apply on input

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hello I am wondering why it is not possible to apply the jQuery UI slider object on an input?

For implementation restrictions I can only apply the jQuery UI slider on an input but that does not works as can be seen here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4ytk198s/). Can anyone tell me whether it is possible to apply it on an input by setting some extra CSS classes / jQuery code or not?

So I need this:

```
<input type="number" class="slider" value="0"></input>
```

to work with this:

```
$(".slider").slider();
```

Comment: do you want to change slider value as inut value change?

Comment: no, default the slider is been created on a `<div>` object. But on a div you can not have this: `<div value="20>` and therefore I need to apply it on an input because I have to send the values to the server via .net postback @DharaParmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned some .net postback, I think you can work around using a hidden input, which should be sent to the server via the postback mechansm (*hopefullly, I'm not into `.net`*):

```js
$('#slider').slider({
  min: 1,
  max: 99,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).next(':hidden').val(ui.value);
    console.log($(this).next(':hidden').val());
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="slide-value">
```

Comment: This indeed the way to go! Thank you! a hidden input works for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

This is the Html part

```
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <p>Your slider has a value of <span class="slider-value"></span></p>
    <input type="number" class="test" value="0"></input>
```

The script will be like below

```
$(".slider").slider(
{
            value:1,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            step: 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( ".slider-value").html( ui.value );
            }
}
);

$( ".slider-value").html(  $('.slider').slider('value') );

$('.test').change(function () {
        var value = this.value;

        $('.slider').slider("value", value);
         $( ".slider-value").html( value );
    })
```

Try this one, it will be work.

Comment: Your thinking is good! But unfortunately the example does not work :(

Comment: @Rotan075 . Sorry I don't  know its not working for you. but actually I've tested it before posting.